# Not able to add html tags through jQuery in django

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am new to jQuery and django.I was writing a code where I am adding radio buttons dynamically through jQuery to my HTML page.

It was working fine when I had a standalone HTML file. But when I clubbed it with my django app its not getting added.

It doesn't even show any errors.

I tried with simple tags like

```
$("#div1").append("<h3>First</h3> ")
```

also

```
$("#div1").append("<br/>")
```

even these are not working.

However the tags are working outside jQuery.

I tried adding simple text via jQuery

```
$("#div1").append("I am here")
```

This is woking fine.

Comment: Are you opening .html file straight from directory. Or are you opening the URL after running the server, like localhost:8000/yourpage.html

Comment: yes i am opening it after running the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was working on a normal html page probably my guess is your jquery library is not loaded when you are serving your html page via django. 
Try using this instead and see if your page is working or not.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try debugging using Chrome javascript console or fire bug

Comment: No it doesnt show any error. I tried with appending simple text like $("#div1").append(" I am here "), these are working fine.

Comment: And yeah even the jquery file is getting accessed when i saw the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong, if you want to select an element with ID you should use ID selector: `$('#div1')` or class selector `$('.div1')`. Currently you are trying to select an element that it's tag name is `div1`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // when DOM is ready
     $("#div1").append("<h3>First</h3>");
     // $(".div1").append("<h3>First</h3>")
})
```